# How to create a 'transform' mixin in SCSS that uses several arguments?

Tags: css, sass, less, scss-mixins

I want to create a mixin for transform that has two arguments - translate and rotate. I've tried it in several ways but none of them works and I do not know why.

```
@mixin transform($transforms) {
    -moz-transform: $transforms;
    -o-transform: $transforms;
    -ms-transform: $transforms;
    -webkit-transform: $transforms;
    transform: $transforms;
}
@mixin rotate ($deg) {
    @include transform(rotate(#{$deg}deg));
}
@mixin translate($x, $y) {
    @include transform(translate($x, $y));
}
```

In nav.scss I included it like this

```
@include transform(rotate(45));
@include transform(translate(0,9px));
```

It doesn't change anything in the presentation page.

Without mixin I simply use:

```
span:before {
         transform: translateY(9px) rotate(45deg);
}
```

and it works but I want to achieve the same result with a mixin, but I don't know how. I started learning SASS a few days ago.

Comment: Two things. You are are trying to nest mixin calls when you do `@include transform(rotate(45))` --  this will call the transform mixin and pass it the value rotate(45) -- notice that you are missing `deg` so its invalid css and will not work. If you want to call the rotate mixin, you have to do `@include rotate(45)`. Second thing, make sure you are using `@include mixin` within a css ruleset under a selector, like span:before { @include myMixin(); } so that the styles it adds are under that selector.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I would recommend you use [**Autoprefixer**](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) to handle vendor prefixes as you'll often add way more prefixes than needed.

In the case of transform, you would probably be fine just adding

```
-webkit-transform: ...;
        transform: ...;
```

Also, it becomes rather hard to handle when you need to deal with property values:

```
  transition: transform 300ms;

  // prefixed  
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms;
          transition: -webkit-transform 300ms;
          transition: transform 300ms;
          transition: transform 300ms, -webkit-transform 300ms;
```

To answer your question I think the easiest way is to use [**argument-lists**](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/lists#argument-lists) (allows any number of arguments to be passed) joined together in a space-separated list:

```
// Mixin 
@mixin transform($transforms...) {
    // combine the passed transforms into a space separated list
    $transform-list: join($transforms, null, space);

    // print out the transforms 
    -webkit-transform: $transform-list;
       -moz-transform: $transform-list;
        -ms-transform: $transform-list;
         -o-transform: $transform-list;
            transform: $transform-list;
}


// Include 
span::before {
    @include transform(
        rotate(90deg),
        translate(0,9px),
        // ... add more transforms if you need
    );
}


// CSS output 
span::before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0, 9px);
       -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0, 9px);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0, 9px);
         -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0, 9px);
            transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0, 9px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to nest the mixins like that. You can take advantage of [optional arguments](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#optional-arguments) and the [keyword syntax](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#keyword-arguments):

```
@mixin transformNew($rotate: 0, $translate: translate(0, 0)) {
  -moz-transform: rotate(#{$rotate}deg) $translate;
    -o-transform: rotate($rotate) $translate;
    -ms-transform: rotate(#{$rotate}deg) $translate;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(#{$rotate}deg) $translate;
    transform: rotate(#{$rotate}deg) $translate;
}

div {
  @include transformNew($translate: translate(10px, 40px));
  background: red;
}
```

The arguments for the mixin now have a default value, if you want to call it with only one argument. You can call arguments explicitly by using the *keyword syntax*. In my example I wanted only the second argument, so I did this: `@include transformNew($translate: translate(10px, 40px));`. If you only need the first argument, then it is enough to just pass the value, no need for the keyword.

If you need both arguments, you can simply pass them both. In your code, if you called the mixin twice, you had overwritten the first value with the second call.
That won't happen here. I also created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/qBbLLLr) for you to play around with the code.